# SQL Server shrinkfile fails with tempdb full of active transactions

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server under Docker / Linux on a Mac. I have a 60Gb database where I have removed around 30Gb of data. I then try and shrink the file with:

```
dbcc shrinkfile('my_database')
```

However this fails with a message saying

tempdb full due to active transactions

I have checked the size of the tempdb transaction log with

```
DBCC SQLPERF('logspace')
```

It is 8Mb. I then checked the settings for the tempdb files in case they were configured with a maximum size, using

```
select * from sys.database_files
```

This shows four "ROWS" files and the transaction log. All five show as max size = -1 i.e. unlimited, and growth of 8192.

I have around 35Gb disk space free.

I cannot see what the problem is here. How can I shrink this database?

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to shrink a database; do you really need to do so?

Comment: For autogrow to work properly you need both `max_size = -1` and `growth > 0`. Are both columns set appropriately?

Comment: @Larnu I'm taking a copy of a database from a production environment, to be anonymised and reduced for use on a testing environment and for local development. I think that is a valid use case for shrinking? A local developer will typically have 10 database installed at any given time, we wouldn't want them all full production size, I mean that could be terabytes in some cases.

Comment: If you're doing that, you're better off creating new databases from your source control, and then `INSERT`ing sample data; then production data never leaves production.

Comment: @Larnu, if we need to test against customer specific configuration, spread across hundreds of database tables, we cannot simply "insert sample data".

Comment: You can `INSERT` anonymised sample data from the production environment, @Hedley . If you're taking a production database, and then shrinking it, and can (or will) cause fragmentation and that could *easily* be disastrous for performance in your dev environment.